# How to output template data line by line

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have some data which is a multiline string. And I don't want to modify it. Now I want to prefix each one with a character

```yaml
{{- define "info.geological" -}}
iWater Well Completion Reports
Anatomy of a Water Well Report
Water table Altitudes
...
{{- end -}}
```

What I want

```yaml
data:
  - "iWater Well Completion Reports"
  - "Anatomy of a Water Well Report"
  - "Water table Altitudes"
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat it as `string` in golang, split and print

template

```yaml
{{- define "info.geological" -}}
iWater Well Completion Reports
Anatomy of a Water Well Report
Water table Altitudes
...
{{- end -}}
```

template/xxx.yaml

```yaml
data: 
{{- $dt := include "info.geological" . }}
{{- range ( split "\n" $dt) }}
  - {{ . | quote }}
{{- end }}
```

output:

```yaml
data:
  - "iWater Well Completion Reports"
  - "Anatomy of a Water Well Report"
  - "Water table Altitudes"
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Helm's [template functions](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/) largely come from a library called [Sprig](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/).  Sprig includes a small number of [functions that operate on lists of strings](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/string_slice.html), more specifically including a `splitList` function.

So, given your multi-line string, you can split it on newlines to get the list of lines

```
{{- $lines := include "info.geological" . | splitList "\n" -}}
```

Once you have that list, the easiest way to emit it as a YAML list is the underdocumented `toYaml` function; so

```yaml
data:
{{ include "info.geological" . | splitList "\n" | toYaml | indent 2 }}
```

You can also manually iterate through it with a `range` loop if you'd like.

```yaml
data:
{{- $lines := include "info.geological" . | splitList "\n" }}
{{- range $lines }}
  - {{ quote . }}
{{- end }}
```